# Using composite key of Latitude and longitude vs auto increment as Primary Key in case of area under city Relational DB

Tags: sql, latitude-longitude, auto-increment, composite-key

Suppose we need to save following data in database

```
County          latdecdeg   londecdeg         State
---------------------------------------------------
Allegheny       40.5254     -80.07213889        PA 
Allegheny       40.5526     -80.1159            PA
Allegheny       40.5191     -80.13090556        PA
Allegheny       40.5134     -80.13508889        PA
Allegheny       40.5228     -80.17644722        PA
Allegheny       40.496      -79.939375          PA
Beaver          40.6957     -80.36681667        PA
Berks           40.2485     -76.03885833        PA
Berks           40.2979     -75.89966111        PA
Blair           40.5622     -78.32684722        PA
Blair           40.6001     -78.31262222        PA
```

---

So is it a good idea to use a combination of Lat and log as primary key ?
OR It is better to have one more column as auto increment primary key .

Also the query will be made on the basis of county and and all its lat and long need to be fetched.

Comment: I'd chose a regular id column as pk.

Comment: Most people here want sample data as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: @jarlh I am new to stack overflow will try to put forward my question in a better way next time  :)

Comment: No problem! We are all here to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an auto-increment primary key.

One of the purposes of a primary key is to provide a key for foreign key references.  In most cases an integer column is the best choice.  In addition, you don't specify what these are, but multiple addresses can be at the same location (the metro in Naples Italy has two subways that are vertically aligned along the side of a hill, for instance).

Further, you never want to use floating point numbers as a primary key.  And that even extends to fixed point decimal numbers.

Add an additional column to identify each row uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, one should  use Auto increment as it's the best way to define primary key of a table since it's managed by the db itself.
For the second part regarding querying on the basis of some columns, Indexing should be beneficial for the purpose.